# Data from Local Storage appending to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

My local storage is now working fine: it's storing the data on a single key.

However, when I'm trying to append the data on HTML I'm getting this output on appending. Please see the image below.

Also, you can see my code here. I really appreciate your help guys. Step by step I'm now understanding the localStorage, but I'm having a road block in this one can anyone help me thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/ricobenviaje11/rp8kqtd9/12/

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  var iDataHandler = [];
  
    $(".save").on("click", function() {
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
          if(localStorage.getItem('iDataHandler') && localStorage.getItem('iDataHandler').length > 0)
            iDataHandler = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('iDataHandler'));
          DataHandler = {
            'title': $("#txtbox-1").val(),
            'para': $("#txtbox-2").val(),
            'para1': $("#txtbox-3").val(),
          };
          
          iDataHandler.push(DataHandler);
          localStorage.setItem('iDataHandler', JSON.stringify(iDataHandler));
        }
      // appending data
          for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(iDataHandler).length; i++) {
          Object.keys(iDataHandler)[i]
          $('.sNote').append(
              '<div class="list-item" data-postid"'+Object.keys(iDataHandler)[i]+'">'+iDataHandler[(Object.keys(iDataHandler)[i])]+
              '</div><div class="close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>'
            );
          }      
        
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="" id="txtbox-1">
<input type="text" name="" id="txtbox-2">
<input type="text" name="" id="txtbox-3">
<div class="save">
Save
</div>


<div class="sNote"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: With localStorage all is right, you have mistake when set data `iDataHandler` to html element

Comment: You must first stringify object ```JSON.stringify(iDataHandler[(Object.keys(iDataHandler)[i])])```

Comment: Thanks, Vitality, can you show me how to do it. I think my mistake there is on appending. My goal is also when I've input on the on the inputs it should be separated for Example
input1: Name
input2: MiddleName
input3: Surname
it should look like this on HTML
<div class="name-c">
<div class="name">Name</div>
<div class="middle">Middle</div>
<div class="surname">Surname</div>
</div>

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, where should I put this? JSON.stringify(iDataHandler[(Object.keys(iDataHandler)[i])])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put this where you append data to `list-item`

```
// appending data
           for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(iDataHandler).length; i++) {
                  $('.sNote').append(
                      '<div class="list-item" data-postid"'+JSON.stringify(iDataHandler[(Object.keys(iDataHandler)[i])])+
                      '</div><div class="close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>'
                    );
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, Vitaliy, It's working now I can see the data into string, also may I ask how can I append it to something like this? 

 Example input1: Name input2: MiddleName input3: Surname it should look like this on HTML <div class="name-c"> <div class="name">Name</div> <div class="middle">Middle</div> <div class="surname">Surname</div> </div>

Comment: See demo https://jsfiddle.net/asv7gbce/

Comment: Hi Vitaliy Can you help me again? I have this problem when I tried it appending the append is right. However, when I tried refreshing the page the append HTML is gone but in the local storage the data still there. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Your data view only on click, if i understand correct, you want to show them right away 
 after refresh?

Comment: Hi Vitaliy thanks for getting back to me, yes even I refresh the page data is still there.

Comment: somehow so, right? https://jsfiddle.net/kuq628a5/

Comment: Hi, Vitaliy thanks for helping again. However, when I tried refreshing the data is I've input is still there however below the data I input there's an empty data that saved.

Comment: every time I refresh it the empty data below is increasing? do you also encountered that?

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/mw1Lx2he/2/

Comment: I updated, check again

Comment: the data has been duplicated Vitaliy

Comment: Refresh fiddle)

Comment: You can optimize code, as you want

Comment: my advice is to rewrite everything without using jquery, try this with reactjs or vuejs

Comment: Yup, pure JS, in the future it will be useful for you